# python return empty list from function

Tags: python

I am sorry to ask such a basic question but I am trying to learn python and don't understand why this does not work. When I run this program on a directory it prints and empty list []. I don't understand why. Can someone help? Python 3.

```
import sys, os, 



def getfiles(currdir):
    myfiles = []
    for file in os.listdir(currdir):
         for file in os.listdir(currdir):
            path = os.path.join(currdir,file)
            if not os.path.isdir(path):
                myfiles.append(path)
            else:
                getfiles(path)
    return(myfiles)




if __name__ == '__main__':
    filedirectory = []
    filedirectory = getfiles(sys.argv[1])
    print(filedirectory)
```

This returns []

Thank you for the help

Comment: Would you mind adding the purpose of this code please?

Comment: Why do you duplicate the loop "for file in os.listdir(curdier):"?

Comment: Is it possible that there are no files in `currdir`? I would suggest hard-coding a path that you know has some files instead of using `sys.argv[1]` as a test.

Comment: Also you don't need the line `filedirectory = []` because the function already returns a list.

Comment: Your code works perfectly fine after removing a few minor syntax errors, and deleting the nested for-loop. Do what pbreach said above, and hard-code a path into the getFiles function.

Answer (score 0):

If i understand you want to get all of the file names in a specific directory. here is my code to do that :

```
Import os
AllFiles = []
AllFiles = os.listdir("your Directory")
```

listdir() return all files name in the specific directory.

Comment: It seems from the code that the OP is trying to make a filesystem-recursive version of what you just wrote (something like `os.walk`).

Comment: Thank you both for the replies. You helped me understand a lot!